# When i use apschedular in my flask app, it always runs the function twice. How do i stop this?

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler

I'm using apscheduler to call a function repeatedly. it works fine but for some reason it calls the function i want to run twice instead of once

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.start()

@scheduler.scheduled_job("cron", id="month", minute="*", hour="*")
def hello():
    print("hello")
```

here is what i have got so far. In the logs every minute, it will show print:

```
hello
hello
```

this tells me the function runs twice and i can't figure out how to stop it.

Comment: How many worker processes are you running?

Comment: Are you running flask in debug mode? Due to the way the auto reloader works code gets run twice unless you switch the reloader off.

Comment: @EAW yep thats the problem. Thanks